# Why is referencing arrays, instead of copying them, bad?

Tags: java

Is it because the advantage of copying a array into another array is that you can have the data added onto the array itself, rather than just referencing a particular memory location?

Comment: It isn't. Duplicating an array does one thing, passing references to it does another thing. Both can be useful at times.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is referencing arrays, instead of copying them, bad?

It isn't bad.  It is just different.

Sometimes you *need* to copy an array:

- you may need to be able to change one copy of the array without the changes being visible in the other copy
- you may need to *prevent* the primary version of the array from being changed by whatever you passed the copy to.

In other cases, it is better (or necessary) to not copy the array:

- if you pass an array to something that doesn't need to / isn't going to make any changes, then passing a reference to the original array is more efficient.
- you may *want* changes to be made to the same array in different places, and those changes to be visible.

You should choose between passing the reference and creating / passing a copy *based on what your application needs* ... not on someone's misguided notions of "good" and "bad".

Comment: Not necessarily true

Answer (score 0):

The intent is important, if you are making another reference, what you have is two variables referring to the same memory, any changes that you make to one will be reflected in other.
when you copy array, you get two different arrays which are independent.